# Strange Windows PowerShell 2.0 Behavior

Tags: powershell

Consider the following PowerShell script:

```
function Alpha {
# write-output 'Uncomment this line and see what happens.';
return 65;
}

function Bravo {
$x = Alpha;
$y = $x -eq 65;
return $y;
}

$z = Bravo;
echo $z;
```

On my computer (which is running Windows XP SP3, .NET 4.0, and PowerShell 2.0 RTM), when the script is run, the script's output is as expected (`True`). However, when "the line" is uncommented (and the script is run again), instead of seeing the same output prepended by `Uncomment this line...`, I am only seeing `65`. Can someone please explain what is going on? Thanks.

Comment: Note that you don't need to end every line with a semi-colon. They are only needed in PowerShell if you put two statements into one line; otherwise a line break suffices. Makes the code less cluttered, imho :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Write-Output` just writes an object *to the pipeline*. If you need a message displayed on the screen, use `Write-Host`.

So, to take apart what happens here, that was kind of a preliminary. If you uncomment the line, both the string `'Uncomment this line and see what happens.'` and the number `65` are outputs of the function, so when calling `Bravo` the variable `$y` no longer holds just a single value but instead the array `'Uncomment this line and see what happens.',65`.

Now the comparison operators work differently if the left operand is an array instead of a scalar value. If the left operand is an array they simply return all elements from the array where the condition would be `$true`. In this case, since you compare with `65`, it will return all items that are equal to `65`. So the result is no longer a boolean but instead an array of objects (or in this case, just a single object) – `65`.

Answer (score 1):

One must be very careful when returning values from a function.
If "echo" (write-output) is used before function's "return" statement, it will damage the return e.g. ... echo "123" ; return $false --- this will resolve to $true.

```
# both function should return $false but the first one is evaluated to $true
function test_NG {Write-Output "this text WILL be included with the return value" ; return $false}
function test_OK {Write-Host   "this text will NOT be included with the return value but visible on the screen" ; return $false}

if (test_NG) {"OK"} else {"NG"}  # this should resolve to NG but is OK because write-output added the text to the return value
if (test_OK) {"OK"} else {"NG"}  # correct result (NG) but the text is always displayed, even during this evaluation
```

Answer (score 0):

@Johannes Rössel: Thank you for your explanation. You know, I am a C# programmer (this explains the semicolons) and I am asking this question because an `echo` debugging statement (a statement which is usually inert in other languages) totally broke my script in strange ways. After tracing down the supposed "strange behavior" for almost an hour, I came up with the script above, narrowing down the "strange behavior" to just two functions.

Thanks to your explanation, now I know two important PowerShell gotchas:

1. that the `echo` (`Write-Output`) statement changes (adds to) a function's return value, and
2. that the `return` statement adds to (instead of sets) a function's return value, possibly to form an array.

Indeed, both gotchas can be verified by running the following PowerShell commands:

```
function Charlie { echo 2; echo 3; echo 5; return 7 }
$a = Charlie
# Nothing is printed.
$a
# Displays the contents of array $a, that is:
# 2
# 3
# 5
# 7
```

Now I probably want to write all my PowerShell debugging statements with the `Write-Warning` statement instead. After all, their outputs are colored yellow, so they can be read and distinguished more easily.

Comment: (a) You can write debug statements with `Write-Debug` which are then only visible if you set your `$DebugPreference` to something else than `SilentlyContinue`. (b) `return foo` is just a shorthand for `foo; return`. `return` just exits the function while *everything* that is simply dumped to the pipeline from a function belongs to that function's output. `function A { 1; 2; 3 }` returns three values, this has nothing to do with `return` per se.